# How to run hcaptcha callback function

Tags: javascript, python, selenium-webdriver, undetected-chromedriver, hcaptcha

I'm trying to run the callback function for the hcaptcha but it keeps giving me the null (reading 'appendChild') error, If anyone has any other suggestions, I'd appreciate it.

```
import os
import threading
import time

import nopecha
import undetected_chromedriver as uc
import tkinter as tk

def solvehCaptcha():
print("başlatıldı!")
nopecha.api_key = '\*'

    # Call the Token API
    token = nopecha.Token.solve(
        type='hcaptcha',
        sitekey='b4c45857-0e23-48e6-9017-e28fff99ffb2',
        url='https://nopecha.com/demo/hcaptcha#easy',
    
    )
    
    
    print(token)
    
    browser.execute_script(f'''                                                                                                                                                             
    document.querySelector('[id^="h-captcha-response-"]').innerHTML = "{token}"                                                                                                             
    ''')
    js_script = f"""
              let captchaElement = document.getElementById('captcha')
              let inputElement = document.createElement('input');
              inputElement.setAttribute('type', 'hidden');
              inputElement.setAttribute('name', 'response_token');
              inputElement.setAttribute('value', "{token}");
              captchaElement.appendChild(inputElement)
    """
    browser.execute_script(js_script)

options = uc.ChromeOptions()
options.set_capability("detach", True)

browser = uc.Chrome(options=options)

browser.get('https://nopecha.com/demo/hcaptcha#easy')

root = tk.Tk()

root.geometry("300x300")

btn = tk.Label(root, text="Başlat", bg="Black", fg="white")
btn.pack(side="top", anchor="center")
btn.bind("\<Button-1\>", lambda e: threading.Thread(target=solvehCaptcha).start())

root.mainloop()
```

Error result:

```
Exception in thread Thread-2: Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\Users\fatih\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\threading.py", line 950, in _bootstrap_inner     self.run()   File "C:\Users\fatih\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\threading.py", line 888, in run     self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)   File "C:\Users\fatih\OneDrive\Masaüstü\Python\reklam-project\test2.py", line 36, in solvehCaptcha     browser.execute_script(js_script)   File "C:\Users\fatih\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 500, in execute_script     return self.execute(command, {"script": script, "args": converted_args})["value"]   File "C:\Users\fatih\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 440, in execute     self.error_handler.check_response(response)   File "C:\Users\fatih\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 245, in check_response     raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace) selenium.common.exceptions.JavascriptException: Message: javascript error: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'appendChild')   (Session info: chrome=113.0.5672.64) Stacktrace: Backtrace:    GetHandleVerifier [0x00FE8893+48451]    (No symbol) [0x00F7B8A1]    (No symbol) [0x00E85058]    (No symbol) [0x00E883F1]    (No symbol) [0x00E89DEB]    (No symbol) [0x00EDCDD9]    (No symbol) [0x00ECA2BC]    (No symbol) [0x00EDC482]    (No symbol) [0x00ECA0B6]    (No symbol) [0x00EA7E08]    (No symbol) [0x00EA8F2D]    GetHandleVerifier [0x01248E3A+2540266]  GetHandleVerifier [0x01288959+2801161]  GetHandleVerifier [0x0128295C+2776588]  GetHandleVerifier [0x01072280+612144]   (No symbol) [0x00F84F6C]    (No symbol) [0x00F811D8]    (No symbol) [0x00F812BB]    (No symbol) [0x00F74857]    BaseThreadInitThunk [0x75800099+25]     RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x77917B6E+286]  RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x77917B3E+238]
```

I want to make the hcaptcha callback without submit button, but I get error: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'appendChild')

Comment: Is there actually an HTML tag with `id=captcha` on the page you've fetched?  That's where you're sending your output.